# Get dynamic page title for the value <input type="hidden" name="field[46]" value=" " />

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement an ActiveCampaign form in Wordpress site. The same form will be using on a different page but I would like to know which page the contacts are coming from. So, I use a hidden filed where the value will be updated dynamically using Javascript I believe but can't figure out how to use javascript to get that. Can anyone help me with this?

value=" " would be change dynamically with the page title.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? You can get the current URL using `window.location.href` and you can set the value of a hidden input using `document.getElementById('inputIDHere').value = whatever`

Comment: I think he is looking for the page title of the document i.e. `document.title`, not the URL? depending on his application, which is unclear (@shohel-rana), he might be better of obtaining his info from the URL

Comment: I am looking for page title. not URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the title from the document via JavaScript (check out [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title) for more details),

`var docTitle = document.title;`

To more easily access your input field from JavaScript side, I would suggest you add an ID to your input field: 
`<input type="hidden" name="field[46]" value="" id="title_field" />`

So what you can now do is to change the value of your `input` field as such:

`document.getElementById('title_field').value = document.title;`

EDIT:
On another note, why do you need to have a hidden field specially for obtaining the title, when you would have obtained the document's title using `document.title`?

EDIT 2: Snippet

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', allContentLoaded, false);

function allContentLoaded() {
  var docTitle = document.title;
  document.getElementById('title_field').value = docTitle;
  console.log(docTitle);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="field[46]" value="" id="title_field" />

<!--For the sake of visibility, I changed the type of your input to text.-->
```

Comment: I have no idea about Javascript whatsoever. I used the hidden filed to get the page title in the Campaign. This is the actual code. https://pastebin.com/p5ewtLq1

Comment: But you would need to obtain and set the title in JavaScript regardless

Comment: And how would I do that? Samleo

Comment: As @alex noted, you need to put all of this in a `<script></script>` tag

Comment: Added a snippet for your reference... For your application I suggest you go read up on some Javascript on w3schools

Comment: I did according to your suggestion but its giving me nothing. here is the complete code: https://pastebin.com/YpLyy4bV   @Samleo

Comment: What does the console.log say

Comment: Its working fine. Thanks Samleo. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

For page title

```
const titleEL = document.getElementByTagName('TITLE'); // Get the title html tag
const hiddenInputEl = document.getElementById('hidden'); // Get hidden input
hiddenInputEl.value = titelEl.textContent // Set input value to the content of the title-tag
```

or if you want the url.

```
hiddenInputEl.value = window.location.href
```

You could also use `document.title` see the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title).

Comment: Is that all, I have to do?  <input type=“hidden” name=“field[46]” value=“const titleEL = document.getElementByTagName('TITLE');” />

Comment: No, that code is not going to work. First because the value will literally be "const titleEL = document.getElementByTagName('TITLE');" and secondly, because `document.getElementsByTagName('title')` returns the DOM element, not it's value, as you seem to be looking for

Comment: You need to have this code within `<script>` tags or in a separate JavaScript file.